# Get variables from each elements child field

Tags: jquery, field, variables

.I have a cart that's just not cooperating. When the checkout button is hit, in addition to submitting the forms, it needs to send some code back to my server pulled from each row's fields.

The HTML (simplified version)

```
<div class="row">
<input type="text" readonly="readonly" class="pp_name" value="Sample product">
<input type="hidden" class="pp_id" value="1234">
<input type="hidden" class="pp_stock" value="5">
</div>

<div class="row">
<input type="text" readonly="readonly" class="pp_name" value="Another item">
<input type="hidden" class="pp_id" value="7456">
<input type="hidden" class="pp_stock" value="2">
</div>

<div class="row">
<input type="text" readonly="readonly" class="pp_name" value="Some other thing">
<input type="hidden" class="pp_id" value="9121">
<input type="hidden" class="pp_stock" value="3">
</div>

<input type="submit" value="Checkout" id="checkout">
```

The script I need to output on submit (it sends my server updated stock counts for each item, calling functions from an API library):

```
$('#checkout').click(function(){

$('.row').each(function(){
var itemId = $('.pp_id').val;
var fieldId = 100;       // This var is a constant, static value
var newStockcount = $('.pp_stock').val;
setapikey(1234567890);
setMetadata( itemId, fieldId, newValue, );
});

});
```

Every single variation I have tried while writing this script has been unable to fetch the values of the fields in each row. There's nothing wrong with the setMetadata function, I'm using it on countless sites without issue. It's simply feeding it the vars from the fields that won't work.

Even if I set an ID for each row and use it to pinpoint the fields, it's no good., i.e.
    $('#checkout').click(function(){

```
$('.row').each(function(){

$(this).attr('id', 'active_checkout_row'); //SET ID

var itemId = $('.pp_id').val;
var fieldId = 100;
var newStockcount = $('.pp_stock').val;
setapikey(1234567890);
setMetadata( itemId, fieldId, newValue, );

$(this).attr('id', 'inactive_checkout_row'); //UNSET ID

});
```

I've been at it for two days, so if some helpful soul could show me where I'm going wrong I'd be very grateful.

Even using the following yields no results:

```
var anyVariable = document.getElementById('active_checkout_row').getElementsByClassName('pp_name').value;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're almost there Jeremy,

When you iterate through each row you need to find each child element. Currently when you iterate through each row you are doing a global search with **$('.pp_id')** but what you actually want to do is find **.pp_id** that is a child of the current row you're on.

Also, in jQuery you need to call **.val()** with parenthesis to fetch the actual value.

Here is a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6PdYL/) of fetching what you want.

HTM remains the same.

JS:

```
$('#checkout').click(function(){

    $('.row').each(function(){
    var itemId = $(this).find('input.pp_id').val();
    var fieldId = 100;       // This var is a constant, static value
    var newStockcount = $(this).find('input.pp_stock').val();
        console.log('itemid:'+itemId+' fieldId:'+fieldId+' newStockcount:'+newStockcount);
    });

});
```

Comment: Tony, you have made my week. Thank you so much!